# Reading Multiple MPU 9250 Sensors using TCA9548A Multiplexer

Tags: esp32, mpu6050, multiplexer

I am trying to read multiple MPU 9250 sensors using TCA9548A multiplexer in ESP 32 and Arduino IDE. Has anyone done that successfully?

I am new to the  area of Arduino coding. I am trying to edit the code in this tutorial for MPU 9250 (https://www.bluedot.space/tutorials/connect-multiple-sensors-using-i2c-multiplexer/). I am facing issues with libraries and commands while shifting from BME 280 to MPU 9250.  Once  I am changing to MPU 9250 and trying to call instance MPU9250 IMU_0, I am getting error "no matching function for call to 'MPU9250", which I understand is because the library I've used doesn't support the call. I am unable to find alternate library or command. How can this be sorted out?

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU9250.h>
MPU9250 mpu_0;
MPU9250 mpu_1;
MPU9250 mpu_2;
MPU9250 mpu_3;

#define TCAADDR 0x70
void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;
 
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.println(F("##############################"));            
  Serial.println(F("Starting Initialization"));
  Serial.println(F("##############################"));       
 
  //*************INITIALIZING FIRST SENSOR*******************************   
  tcaselect(0);
    
  if (mpu_0.begin() != 0x68)
  { Serial.print(F("MPU.1 detected?\t")); Serial.println(F("No"));}
  else
  { Serial.print(F("MPU.1 detected?\t")); Serial.println(F("Yes"));}
  //**********************************************************************
  //*************INITIALIZING SECOND SENSOR*******************************  
  tcaselect(1);  
    
  if (mpu_1.begin() != 0x68)
  { Serial.print(F("MPU Nr.2 detected?\t")); Serial.println(F("No"));}
  else
  { Serial.print(F("MPU Nr.2 detected?\t")); Serial.println(F("Yes"));}
  //*********************************************************************      
  //**********************************************************************  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("##############################"));            
  Serial.println(F("Initialization Finished"));
  Serial.println(F("##############################"));            
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: "I am facing *issues*".  What issues?

Comment: Your code is nearly impossible to read.  You might consider editing your question and using the code formatting facilities on the page.

Comment: Which MPU9250 library are you using? Did you look at its examples to fix your code?

Comment: I see no question being asked

Comment: I am using MPU 9250 library from bolder-flights system. In the tutorial about multiplexer, they have used BME280 and BlueDot_BME280library. Once  I am changing to MPU 9250 and trying to call instance MPU9250 IMU_0, I am getting error "no matching function for call to 'MPU9250", which I understand is because the library I've used doesn't support the call. I am unable to find alternate library or command. What alternatives can I use or how can I achieve taking readings from Multiple MPU9250 simultaneously using a multiplexer?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt the example you're following to follow how the MPU library does its construction and setup.

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/bolderflight/MPU9250) for the MPU library you are using, you should change the definitions to:

```cpp
MPU9250 mpu_0(Wire, 0x68);  // 0x69 if you pulled AD0 high
```

Then if you read further to the "Common Setup Functions" section, you'll see that this library's `setup` function has this behavior:

> This function returns a positive value on a successful initialization and returns a negative value on an unsuccesful initialization

So you need to adapt that too:

```cpp
Serial.print(F("MPU.1 detected?\t"));
if (mpu_0.begin() < 0) { // the examples assume zero is ok too
  Serial.println(F("No"));
} else {
  Serial.println(F("Yes"));
}
```

You'll save yourself some trouble if you use an array for your sensors too.

```cpp
MPU9250 mpus[] = { MPU9250(Wire, 0x68), MPU9250(Wire, 0x68) }; 
const int num_mpus = sizeof(mpus)/sizeof(mpus[0]);
```

Then your initialization can be done with a loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < num_mpus; ++i) {
   tcaselect(i);
   if (mpus[i].begin() < 0) {
     // ...
   }
 }
```

And you can do similar things for interacting with the sensor. e.g.:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < num_mpus; ++i) {
   tcaselect(i);
   mpus[i].readSensor();
   Serial.println(mpus[i].getAccelX_mss());
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou very much... I would try implementing these..